# Matlab is showing Error using im2frame

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I am trying to modify video frames and convert them to back to video format by using im2frame. There is no error if I do this operation from first frame of unprocessed video, however if I start this process from for example 30th frame or 40th frame then error comes as "Error using im2frame Indexed movie frame must have a non-empty colormap". How can I solve this ?

Edit : Video has over 2000 frames.

Thanks in advance.

My code is as following,

```
% create the video writer with 1 fps
 writerObj = VideoWriter('myVideo3.avi');
 writerObj.FrameRate = 1;
 % set the seconds per image
 secsPerImage = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
 % open the video writer
 open(writerObj);
 % write the frames to the video
 for u=1:length(images)
     % convert the image to a frame
     frame = im2frame(images{u});
     for v=1:secsPerImage(u) 
         writeVideo(writerObj, frame);
     end
 end
 % close the writer object
 close(writerObj);
```

Comment: provide your code...

Comment: You didn't provide any **relevant** information about the error. How's your data look like? How you try to access it? How do you call `im2frame`? Attach here some of your code.

Comment: I attached now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your writerObj.FrameRate doesn't match your secsPerImage vector. 
You're defining two different framerates basically.

The for-loop which the writeVideo() lies in cannot get the number of frames per second it expects and probably therefore finds an empty index, hence no colormap available.

Comment: But there is not a problem if I take frames from 1 to 11. Problem occurs if I take lets say 2 to 12 or 10 to 20.

Comment: Because you have only 11 elements in `secsPerImage `, so you can't access its 12th place. Try for example 2 to 11, and it will work...

Comment: Please add the code from where you initialize the variable "images". And what is the reason for the vector secsPerImage?